# IF with "AND" and "OR" condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create a formula that does the following

If A1 = "4" AND (A2 = 0 OR A2 = "") THEN SHOW "A", Otherwise show "B"

I am just not sure of how to get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
=IF(AND(A1=4,OR(A2=0,A2="")),"A","B")
```